# User Input to a Value Stored in an Integer Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, integer

I'm trying to make it so every time the user inputs a value, it's stored in an array in a place that represents a stat. Hard to explain so here's the code:

```
void MainChar::CharacterCreation()
```

{
    int statPoints = 20;

```
int health             = 0;
int magicDamage        = 0;
int magicResist        = 0;
int physicalResist     = 0;
int physicalDamage     = 0;
int magicOffMastery    = 0;
int physicalOffMastery = 0;
int magicDefMastery    = 0;
int physicalDefMastery = 0;

// SETS STATS AND THIER RESPECTIVE ARRAY PLACEMENT
int statArray[9];

statArray[0] = health;
statArray[1] = magicDamage;
statArray[2] = magicResist;
statArray[3] = physicalResist;
statArray[4] = physicalDamage;
statArray[5] = magicOffMastery;
statArray[6] = physicalOffMastery;
statArray[7] = magicDefMastery;
statArray[8] = physicalDefMastery;

std::string stats[9];
stats[0] = "Health : "                    ;
stats[1] = "Magic Damage : "              ;
stats[2] = "Magic Resist : "              ;
stats[3] = "Physical Resist : "           ;
stats[4] = "Physical Damage : "           ;
stats[5] = "Magic Offensive Mastery : "   ;
stats[6] = "Physical Offensive Mastery : ";
stats[7] = "Magic Defensive Mastery : "   ;
stats[8] = "Physical Defensive Mastery : ";

int statString = 0;
int statInt    = 0;

while (statPoints > 0)
{

    std::cout << "*******************************************************************************" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*                                                                             *" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*                            CHARACTER CREATION                               *" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*                                                                             *" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*******************************************************************************" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "          Health                            :                     "                 << health * 10        << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "          Magic Damage                      :                     "                 << magicDamage        << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "          Magic Resist                      :                     "                 << magicResist        << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "          Physical Resist                   :                     "                 << physicalResist     << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "          Physical Damage                   :                     "                 << physicalDamage     << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "          Magic Offensive Mastery           :                     "                 << magicOffMastery    << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "          Physical Offensive Mastery        :                     "                 << physicalOffMastery << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "          Magic Defensive Mastery           :                     "                 << magicDefMastery    << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "          Physical Defensive Mastery        :                     "                 << physicalDefMastery << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*******************************************************************************" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "STAT POINTS: " << statPoints                                                     << std::endl;
    std::cout << stats[statString]  ;
    std::cin  >> statArray[statInt] ;

    statPoints -= statArray[statInt];
    ++statString;
    ++statInt;
}
```

}

As you might notice, I'm trying to have the user change the value of health, which is stored in statArray[statInt], which equates to statArray[0], then I ++statInt. The idea was I'd be able to have the user input all his stats one at a time. Instead of my intention, whats happening is it's taking the user input as a reference to the array slot. (statArray[0], statArray[1]) etc. Instead of the stat associated with that array slot.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want to do you could use a union:

```
union Stat {
  struct {
   int health;
   int magicDamage;
   int magicResist;
   // ...
  };
  int array[3];
};

int main() {
  Stat stat;
  stat.array[1] = 42;
  cout<<stat.magicDamage<<endl; // should give 42
};
```

However a better solution would be to use a map:

```
map<string,int> stat;
const char *keys[] = {"health","magicDamage","magicResist"};

int main() {
  for (int i=0;i<3; ++i) {
    cout<<"enter "<<keys[i]<<endl;
    cin>>stat[keys[i]];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `statArray`definition to use pointers instead of values

```
int *statArray[9];

statArray[0] = &health;
statArray[1] = &magicDamage;
statArray[2] = &magicResist;
statArray[3] = &physicalResist;
statArray[4] = &physicalDamage;
statArray[5] = &magicOffMastery;
statArray[6] = &physicalOffMastery;
statArray[7] = &magicDefMastery;
statArray[8] = &physicalDefMastery;
```

And update next lines:

```
std::cout << *stats[statString]  ;
std::cin  >> *statArray[statInt] ;

statPoints -= *statArray[statInt];
```